# In jsonata how to convert object to array

Tags: json, jsonata

```
{a="abc", B="add"}
```

To

```
[a="abc", B="add"]
```

How to convert `object` to `array`

Comment: `[a="abc", B="add"]` is not a valid JSON. Could you provide a valid example of the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

To convert `{"a": "abc", "B": "add"}` to  `[{"a": "abc", "B": "add"}]`, you could use the following JSONata expression:

```
[$]
```

[Here's a link](https://www.stedi.com/jsonata/playground?statev2=eJyLjlYqzi8tSk5V0lFKrSgoSi0uzszPA3ISawxqDIF0dYxSYoySlQKQSkqOUdIBMpyg%2FJSUGKVaoJJolVggmV9jVGNcY6IUq6NkqhQLALNCGVc%3D) where you can play around with it on the JSONata playground.